# Avoid a weird error with ltablex

Tags: tables, tabularx, ltablex

I'd like to have an table over many pages with the same headline. I use the `tabularx` package, and the `ltablex` is required according to [link](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=4485). However if I use `ltablex` I get sticky errors `! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.` Any idea how to solve it? A minimal example follows.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for tables http://www.lapomori.com/
%\usepackage{ltablex} 
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Example of an table}
\label{tab:daypack}     
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}cX@{}}  
\toprule
\textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\[6pt]
\midrule
%\endhead
$R$ & 1This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 2As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 3Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 4This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 5As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 6Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 7This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 8As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 9Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 10This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 11As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 12Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 13This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 14As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 15Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 16This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 17As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 18Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 19This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 20As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 21Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 22This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 23As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 24Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 25This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 26As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 27Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 28This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 29As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 30Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 31This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 32As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 33Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 34This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
$R$ & 35As well as the line before \\[6pt]
$A$ & 36Also this is an example \\[6pt]
$R$ & 37This is an example sentence \\[6pt]
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx} \\   
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The no line here to end message is an indication of misuse of `\\` which should almost never be used outside of an alignment.

Remove this one:

```
\end{tabularx}% \\
```

Comment: Thank you! it works, but it is not "printed" on two pages. Even if I activate (uncomment) `%\usepackage{ltablex}` and `%\endhead` respectively.

Comment: It won't break over a page if you use a `table` environment.

Comment: Thank you, I used the `table` environment because it was given in an example. Im very new in LaTeX and don't know exactly why if the `table` environment is removed, it doesn't work. Is it possible to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I think that "\ [6pt]" works only inside of \begin{align}-\end{align} and \begin{eqnarray}-\end{eqnarray}. There shouldn't use "$ $".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. `\\[6pt]` can also be used inside `tabular` and friends. However something like `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}` might be the better approach here.